# How to work around a framework incompatible with simulators?

Tags: swift, xcode, xcframework

I'm working with a framework that is device-only compatible. The problem is if I add it to my app, I can't run my app on simulator anymore.

I asked the framework dev to work with me and provide me with a simulator AND device compatible framework, but the best they could do is come up with two versions: one that is device-only compatible and one that is simulator-only compatible.

I have a two questions:

1. Is it really that difficult to make a framework both device and simulator compatible?
2. Is there an environmental variable I could use in the relevant run script, which would tell me if I'm building for simulator or device? My idea is to add the two framework versions and pick one based on the current build architecture.

Any suggestion is welcome. I've been trying to wrap my head around this for a while and I'm not very well versed on the subject.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you convert the framework into a Swift Package?

Comment: Are there any benefits to doing that?

Comment: So it might work on a Simulator? I’m just guessing.

Comment: I don't believe so, unfortunately. It's a problem with whatever architectures the framework supports.

Comment: Apple has a few sessions on the topic in past WWDC just look at the ones about packages.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I am confused with your question,

I am considering that you are talking about XCFramework.

**For XCFramework first of all Go to Xcode >> File >> New >> Target >> Framework**

[image]

Put your source code in this Framework.
Set **Build Libraries for Distribution >> Yes** in Build Settings

and build once.

After Successfully build, Go to your Framework Source Folder and run below 3 different command one by one in Framework Project Terminal.

Replace FRAMEWORK_NAME To your Framework Name

**// For iPhone //**

xcodebuild archive 
-scheme FRAMEWORK_NAME 
-configuration Release 
-destination 'generic/platform=iOS' 
-archivePath './build/FRAMEWORK_NAME.framework-iphoneos.xcarchive' 
-sdk iphoneos 
SKIP_INSTALL=NO 
BUILD_LIBRARIES_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES

**// For Simulator //**

xcodebuild archive 
-scheme FRAMEWORK_NAME 
-configuration Release 
-destination 'generic/platform=iOS Simulator' 
-archivePath './build/FRAMEWORK_NAME.framework-simulator-x86_64.xcarchive' 
-sdk iphonesimulator 
SKIP_INSTALL=NO 
BUILD_LIBRARIES_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES

**// For Combine Two Framework xcarchive //**

xcodebuild -create-xcframework 
-framework './build/FRAMEWORK_NAME.framework-simulator-x86_64.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/FRAMEWORK_NAME.framework' 
-framework './build/FRAMEWORK_NAME.framework-iphoneos.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/FRAMEWORK_NAME.framework' 
-output './build/FRAMEWORK_NAME.xcframework'

After Successfully run above commands you will see, there is one '**Build**' folder was created which contains simulator and iPhone xcarchive with Final framework.

[image]

Done with Your Final XCFramework, which you can use for both iPhone and simulator.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but that's not really what I'm talking about. I have a third party .framework I'm trying to add to my application. It runs only on device. I can't add it and restrict my app to run only on device. So, I'm looking for a way to unlink the framework when I run my app on simulator.

Comment: I think without original source code you can't do much more with .framework